# How to update the JHipster project after updating JHipster generator?

Tags: java, spring, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I updated my JHipster installation as per this [page](http://jhipster.github.io/2014/02/19/jhipster-release-0.11.0.html) by running the command

```
npm update -g generator-jhipster
```

But to update my application I am not sure where should I run the next command `yo jhipster`.

I tried running it from the root of existing project, but it asked me to enter the name of the new project.

[image: Jhipster console]

I tried running it at one level above the root of existing project, then also it asked me the name of the new project. But this time I entered the same name and the jhipster generation process ran. However there was no change in any of the major files like package.json or Gruntfile.js or bower.json

What is the correct way to update a JHipster project, once the JHipster generator is updated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JHipster developers replied over twitter saying that `yo jhipster` has to be executed at the project root folder.

Answer (score 9):

Following [jhipster releases] (https://jhipster.github.io/2015/05/31/jhipster-release-2.14.2.html):
How to upgrade

Update your version of JHipster with:

```
npm update -g generator-jhipster
```

And then you can update your project when you run again

```
yo jhipster
```

You can also update your entities by running again the entity sub-generator, for example if your entity is named Foo

```
yo jhipster:entity Foo
```

Comment: This does not work for me (3.1.0 -> 3.2.0). Install is ok (3.2.0) for new projects but existing ones are still bound to 3.1.0

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing.  Jhipster generator reports 3.1.0 against existing app, but reports 3.2.0 in when run in new directory.

Answer (score 6):

`JHipster` now has a page on **Upgrading an application**.

https://jhipster.github.io/upgrading-an-application/

**TL;DR**

**Running the upgrade sub-generator**

Go into the application’s root directory:

`cd myapplication/`

*To upgrade your application, type:*

`yo jhipster:upgrade`

*If you want to run the upgrade sub-generator even if no new JHipster version is available, type:*

`yo jhipster:upgrade --force`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to update all entities you need to run

```
yo jhipster --with-entities
```

from the **root of your project**

Answer (score 0):

Our jHipster monolithic project is based on an older build of the generator, and still reliant on bower / angularjs for the client. Thus the auto-update ability would never work.

I've been manually updating spring-boot-starter-parent every other sprint to try and bring it up into 2.x parity, but am still unable to leave the 1.5.x version stream due to various dependency issues with (mainly) Hibernate.

As a possible suggestion if you're in the same boat with your own monolithic project:

- Pull down select versions of the jhipster-generator
- Generate a "hello world" starter monolithic project
- Compare the generated pom.xml with your own project
- Compare the generated entity and configuration files with your own project

Answer (score 0):

Run below command at the root of your project.  Also, make sure to delete nodemodules and target folders before upgrading the project.

yo jhipster:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

jhipster --force --with-entities this is how i do it (npm)