# jHipster create entity not prompting for relationships?

Tags: jhipster

According to the documentation, after entering fields the wizard should ask me about relationships. Instead it skips this step entirely and just goes ahead and creates the files. I'm sure this used to work but I don't see what I could have done to break it?

I'd be happy to provide more info but not sure where to look.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB? Relationships only work with SQL databases

Comment: Using MySQL. Makes me wonder if somehow it thinks I'm on mongo though. I'll check when I get time.

Comment: I just tried it with a fresh application. I started from scratch but answered the project init questions in the same way. I'm using MySQL for both dev and prod. Generate an entity and it still doesn't ask about the relationships. I guess it can only be one of the answers I gave or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather embarrassingly I've found the solution. It's been a few weeks since first installing jHipster and beginning to really try creating entities. I created a couple of simple ones to begin with and then played around with it to work out how I was going to use it.

Now I'm ready to start generating entities I looked at the website again and it says about these relationships. I think this is a new feature that has been added since I first installed jHipster though.

In the end I ran this

```
npm update -g generator-jhipster
```

And then when I tried to create an entity I got the question about relationships. Not sure if I need to somehow update my project to the new jHipster version now too.
[How to update the JHipster project after updating JHipster generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680663/how-to-update-the-jhipster-project-after-updating-jhipster-generator)